# Why isn't my sendEmailVerification(beforeUpdatingEmail) function always returning an error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get an email verification email to send before updating a user's email address. At the moment, however, this is not working. I'm not sure why. I've tried a variety of different approaches. I think it may be due to what I'm putting as the String after `user?.sendEmailVerification(beforeUpdatingEmail: )` but I'm not sure. Any help would be really appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
@IBAction func setEmailIsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            let error = validateEmailField()
            if error != nil {
                print(error!) //Needs a Label
            }
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
             let emailSearch = db.collection("users")
                let email = emailTextField.text!
            let query = emailSearch.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                 if let error = error {
                    print("An error was encountered")
                 } else {
                     if snapshot!.isEmpty {
                        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                        user?.sendEmailVerification(beforeUpdatingEmail: self.emailTextField.placeholder!, completion: { (error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print("Error sending update email")
                            } else {
                                print("Success")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks quite different from the `Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in` in the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing in the `email` instead of the `UITextField`'s `placeholder` as parameter, like this:

```
user?.sendEmailVerification(beforeUpdatingEmail: email, completion: { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error sending update email")
    } else {
        print("Success")
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried doing that, and it's still returning an error instead of success. Do you have any more ideas?